# Decorate main with try-except referencing to main instance

Tags: python, class, decorator

I have a template script as follows.

```
from shared import C

def do(ins):
    ins.x()

def main():
    try:
        ins = C(1,'a')
        do(ins)
    except:
        ins.handle()
    else:
        ins.finalize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to move try-except-else in decorator to avoid code duplication in every script based on template?

I create a decorator `dec` like below in `shared.py` which also contains `class C`

```
from functools import wraps

def dec(ins):
    def a(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def b(*a, **k):
            try:
                f(*a, **k)
            except:
                ins.handle()
            else:
                ins.finalize()
        return b
    return a
```

**Failed attempt 1**: Create instance in main and pass to main2

```
from shared import C, dec

def do(ins):
    ins.x()

@dec(ins)
def main():
    ins = C(1, 'a')
    do(ins)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Failed attempt 2**: Set ins within decorator

```
from shared import C, dec

def do(ins):
    ins.x()

@ins = dec(C(1, 'a'))
def main():
    do(ins)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Failed attempt 3**: Create instance in main idiom

```
from shared import C, dec

def do(ins):
    ins.x()

@dec(ins)
def main():
    do(ins)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ins = C(1, 'a')
```

**Successful attempt**: Global variable

```
from shared import C, dec

ins = C(1, 'a')

def do(ins):
    ins.x()

@dec(ins)
def main():
    do(ins)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to avoid creating global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You could modify your class do do the handling, which removed the need of a decorator.

```py
class C:

   def execute(self, func):
       try:
            func(self)
       except:
            self.handle()
       else:
            self.finalize()


def main():
    ins = C(1, 'a')
    C.execute(do)
```

You can achieve this by wrapping the do functions which has all necessary infos.

```py
def do_wrapper(do_func):
    @wraps(do_func)
    def wrapped_do(ins):
        try:
            do_func(ins)
        except:
            ins.handle()
        else:
            ins.finalize()
    return wrapped_do

@do_wrapper
def do(ins):
    ins.x()

def main():
    ins = C(1, 'a')
    do(ins)
```

Note you can also wrap functions 'on-the-fly' which previously were not wrapped.

```py
def main2():
    do_wrapper(do)(ins) # here the do function is wrapped on the fly
```

Comment: Thanks. But, this requires the wrapper to be part of the main script. The idea was to move try-except inside decorator function to shared.py, so as to make template shorter.

Comment: Made an edit, that works on the class without decorators.